# How do I compute the diffraction efficiency of the orders of an arbitrary grating in the Fraunhofer regime?

Tags: optics, fourier-transform, diffraction

Suppose I have an arbitrary grating and it has some transmission profile $t(x)$. I want to compute the diffraction efficiency of the grating's $n^{th}$ order in the Fraunhofer regime. Let the spatial frequency of the grating be $P$.

I know the method is supposed to be somewhat as follows:

1. Write $t(x)$ as a Fourier series and compute the complex Fourier coefficients.
2. The diffraction efficiency of the $n^{th}$ grating is the $n^{th}$ Fourier series coefficients, squared.

Now, the $n^{th}$ complex Fourier coefficients are given as:

$$\frac{1}{P}\int_{-\frac{P}{2}}^{\frac{P}{2}}t(x)e^{\frac{-2\pi j n x}{P}} dx$$

And I am confused on how to actually compute this integral. I don't understand how to compute it for any order of magnitude. I have noticed that the form of the integral is almost the Fourier transform, but I am struggling with the $P$ in the denominator of the exponential. I realize that I can think of the integral as the Fourier transform from $x$-space to $\frac{n}{P}$-space, but I am not sure whether this understanding is correct. What am I missing?

Comment: It seems to me that instead of having "*the spatial frequency of the grating be P*", you have, in fact, set the width of the aperture to be $P$. If you know what a Riemann integral is and the transparency of the aperture $t(x)$ is also a given function, then what is it that you do not understand how to calculate?

Comment: Specifically, is there a way I can get the complex Fourier coefficients from the ordinary Fourier transform, rather than calculating an integral every time? (edit: for every n)

Comment: If $A(\xi)=\mathcal {F}[a(x)]=\int_{\infty}^{\infty}e^{-j2\pi \xi x}a(x)dx$ and $t(x) = 0 \text{ when } |x|>\tfrac{P}{2}$, then with $T(f)=\mathcal F[t(x)]$ your integral is $T_n=\frac{1}{P}T(\tfrac{n}{P})$

Comment: Ah, okay. Would this formula still be valid if $t(x)$ was not 0 outside my period? For example, something like $sin(x)$ - it's definitely not 0 for $|x|>\frac{2\pi}{2}$. (Even though asking about $sin(x)$ is cheating a little, I think the question is valid

Comment: In your formula you have a division by $P$ that represents the width of the aperture outside of which the transparency $t(x)=0$ by definition, and you cannot just let $P\to \infty$. If you set $t(x) =\sin (2\pi \tfrac{x}{A})$ where $A$ is the periodicity then its Fourier transform is $\tfrac{1}{2j}(\delta(\xi - \frac{1}{A}) +\delta(\xi + \frac{1}{A}))$ and it shows that a plane wave going through a sinusoidal transparency will split (diffract) into two beams, one in each spatial direction $\pm\tfrac{1}{A}$